# how to make a drop down menu fixed from the top with css?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want to make a drop menu like the one in http://www.homeshop18.com/ with css only without jquery in particular the All category menu.I have tried css drop down menu but the problem is i am unable to fix the second level menu at the top. any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't understand what you problem is from the way you posted the question but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CrMEc/1/) is a quick menu I put together that only uses CSS that functions like the menu on the site you posted.

HTML:

```
<ul class="main">
    <li>all
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>books
                <ul class="sub2">
                    <li>fiction</li>
                    <li>biography</li>                    
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>mobile
                <ul class="sub2">
                    <li>android</li>
                    <li>cmda</li>                    
                    <li>battery</li>
                </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul>    
    </li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
li {
 border:1px solid;
 padding:1px;
}

.main {
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;    
}

.sub, .sub2 {
 list-style:none;
 position:absolute;  
 display:none;
 width:75px;    
}

.sub2 { 
 float:left;
 left:75px; 
 top:0px;    
}

.main li:hover .sub,
.sub li:hover .sub2{
 display:block;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick solution